# Rpi freezes when I want to look at my cam pics or even when I want to copy the folder to my local pc

Tags: raspbian, networking, samba

I have a rpi that gets the snapshots of my 2 ip cams over FTP. All devices are cable connected (rj45). In between a simple unmanaged gigabit switch. The pictures are saved on a usb HDD of 500Gig (connected to the rpi). I keep my pics for about two months. So that's a lot of pictures.

Every time (without exception) that I want to check my pics on my local desktop (Win10) via Explorer then the rpi gets stuck. He does that after he loads on the screen (thumbnail) lets say the 60th picture. Only remedy is a hard reset (plug out plug in power). If I do a clean reboot via shell (connected through ssh), then he reboots but doesn't comes up again. So again hard reset needed.

Same behavior when I want to copy a folder of 1 day with camera pics. The copy starts and approximately half way he gets stuck again.

I tried to do the same with a Linux device (VM Mint). Same behavior as on the Windows host. It gets stuck and needs a reboot.

Could it be because of the number of pics? 24h or 1 day can count +500 pics (jpeg). I thought cpu could be the issue but when I issue TOP:

```
top - 11:59:00 up 20 min,  4 users,  load average: 3.69, 1.81, 0.94
Tasks: 119 total,   1 running, 118 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  1.3 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id, 96.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :    432.4 total,     27.9 free,    104.2 used,    300.3 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    100.0 total,     99.0 free,      1.0 used.    273.1 avail Mem

 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
1235 pi        20   0   10416   3016   2464 R   2.3   0.7   0:00.40 top
   7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3   0.0   0:03.76 ksoftirqd/0
 269 root      20   0   50200   3960   2880 S   0.3   0.9   0:02.22 rsyslogd
1221 pi        20   0   12220   4152   3360 S   0.3   0.9   0:00.07 sshd
   1 root      20   0   15280   7956   6384 S   0.0   1.8   0:09.14 systemd
   2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 kthreadd
   5 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   0.0   0.0   0:00.42 kworker/u2:0+flush-8:0
   6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq
   8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 kdevtmpfs
   9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 netns
  10 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:01.41 kworker/0:1-events_power_efficient
  11 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 khungtaskd
  12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 oom_reaper
  13 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 writeback
  14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kcompactd0
  15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 crypto
  16 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kblockd
  17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 watchdogd
```

Some additional info:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc# proftpd -v
ProFTPD Version 1.3.6

pi@raspberrypi:/var/log $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.118+ #1311 Mon Apr 27 14:16:15 BST 2020 armv6l GNU/Linux

root@raspberrypi:~# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
└─sda1        8:1    0 465.8G  0 part /media/pi/IPCAMDISK
mmcblk0     179:0    0  14.9G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0   2.4G  0 part
├─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0     1K  0 part
├─mmcblk0p5 179:5    0    32M  0 part
├─mmcblk0p6 179:6    0   256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p7 179:7    0  12.2G  0 part /
```

I also viewed /var/log but nothing to find there. When rpi is not accessible anymore through Windows Explorer, it still is via ssh and I can view logs. But nothing happens in the logs at that moment.

Comment: This sounds like a Windows Explorer/Samba problem rather than a Pi problem.

Comment: What connection uses the MS Windows Explorer? FTP or samba or what? What connection is used by the Linux device (VM Mint)?